# statically allocated variable when using getpwnam()

Tags: c, unix

I'm studying system programming.

There are so many functions which returns variable that is statically allocated.

One of them, there is `getpwnam()`.

So, in the book example what I am reading:

`printf("%ld %ld\n", (long)(getpwnam("tsr")->pw_uid), (long)(getpwnam("avr")->pw_uid));`

both, returns same uid, although, in the `/etc/passwd`, their uids are different.
And, explain why.

This is the question.

But, I thought that this is because of statically allocated variable. But, the result is that the output is different(for example, like 3001, 3005).

Why is the output different?

According to the book, the output should be same.

And, is returning statically allocated variable like local variable(automatic variable) in functions?

For example:

```
char* func(const char** name)
{
    char str[256];
    strcpy(str,name);
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is free to call `getpwname` and then access the `pw_uid` field in whatever order it prefers.

For example, it may generate code that goes like this:

```
struct passwd *pw1 = getpwname("tsr");
struct passwd *pw2 = getpwname("avr");
long uid1 = pw1->pw_uid;
long uid2 = pw2->pw_uid;
printf("%ld %ld\n", uid1, uid2);
```

which will print the same number, since both calls to `getpwname` return a pointer to the same `static` variable, and the second one overwrites the content written by the first one before we had a chance to get the data we needed. This is how the book expected things to go.

On the other hand, the compiler may also choose to do something like

```
struct passwd *pw1 = getpwname("tsr");
long uid1 = pw1->pw_uid;
struct passwd *pw2 = getpwname("avr");
long uid2 = pw2->pw_uid;
printf("%ld %ld\n", uid1, uid2);
```

In this case, the information we need (the UID) is saved in another variable before the second call to `getpwname`.

It's important to stress that both ways of generating the code are legal for the compiler (technically, there are no sequence points between the arguments to a function, so side effects may happen in any order), so you should write your code explicitly as in this second example to make sure that it'll always work correctly.

(by the way, in general it's better to avoid these surprises by favoring the reentrant versions of these functions - for example, `getpwnam_r` doesn't return a pointer to static data that is overwritten at the next call, but fills the structure you provide)

> And, is returning statically allocated variable like local variable(automatic variable) in functions?

Not exactly; returning a pointer to a local variable is illegal, because that variable "logically ceases to exist" when the function returns, so you are returning a pointer to memory you no longer own; in practice, whenever its location on the stack is reused (e.g. at whatever next function call, or in simply later in your function) such memory is unpredictabily overwritten with unrelated data.

Returning a pointer to a statically allocated variable (i.e. a global or a `static` local - which is actually just a a global in disguise) instead is legal - that memory is yours and isn't going anywhere - but since it's shared between all calls to that function it's bound to get overwritten at the next call to the function in question. This makes writing code that uses such a function in nested calls complex, and thread-safe or async-safe (as in: usable in signal handlers) code downright impossible.

Comment: Thank you for well-explained answer. Can you explain more about my added question ? When I call `printf` for each `Getpwnam_()`, it's fine. But calling two `Getpwnam_()` in one `printf()` gives me an seg fault.

Comment: @A.Cho: thank you =) ; on StackOverflow typically you don't add questions to the same post - once a problem is solved you can mark an answer as "accepted", then, if there's another problem, you post another separate question.

Comment: Thank you, I just post another question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, `getpwnam` returns a pointer to a static storage, and it may be overwritten by subsequent calls to `getpwent`, `getpwnam` or `getpwuid`. That's why you saw the inconsistent result. As a recommendation, you can use the reentrent variant of these functions, `getpwnam_r` and `getpwuid_r`, the return the information to a user supplied buffer, rather than static buffer.

> And, is returning statically allocated variable like local variable(automatic variable) in functions?

The difference is that data of static storage are initialized once and exists in the entire lifetime of the program, which automatic variables only exist in the block that it was defined. So in your example, the `str` array does not exists any more when the function `func` returns, and use it is undefined bahavior. In the case of static, it is ok though.

```
char* func(const char** name)
{
    static char str[256];
    strcpy(str,name);
    return str;
}
```

But keep in mind that use of static data often result the function being not reentrent.